# I have fixed select option list in HTML/CSS. I am trying to link it django char field.But Not finding a way through

Tags: python, html, django

Following is Django Form Field i have defined.

```
source_currency = forms.CharField(max_length=5)
```

Following is Select/Option HTML

```
    <select name="fancySelect" for="{{ form.source_currency.id_for_label }}" class="makeMeFancy" id="drop1">

        <!-- Notice the HTML5 data attributes -->

        <option value="BTC" selected="selected" data-skip="1" data-icon="assets/images/large/bitcoin.png" data-html-text="BTC&lt;i&gt">BTC<span class="select_coin_button_arrow">▾</span></option>
        <option value="BTC" data-icon="assets/images/small/bitcoin.png" data-html-text="BTC&lt;i&gt" >BTC</option>
        <option value="ETH" data-icon="assets/images/small/ether.png" data-html-text="ETH&lt;i&gt;">ETH</option>
```

How They can be linked so that on submit These values are passed as string?

Comment: Hey @ChiragJain, I was wondering, did any of  solution helped you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ChoiceField` instead `CharField`, it will automatically pass selected value as string.

```
source_currency = forms.ChoiceField(
    label=_("Source Currency"),
    help_text=_("..."),
    widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'makeMeFancy'}),
    choices=((1, _("BTC")), (2, _("ETH")),),
    initial=1
)
```

**UPDATE**

Alternatively, If you want to connect your existing integration with backend.

> **Note:** value of `name` attribute of *select* tag should be `source_currency`
>   not `fancySelect`

Comment: I have large list of choices is there a way to read it directly from html?

Comment: It doesn't matter if you have large list. you can always handle it from backend.

Comment: check my Update section

Comment: Hey i am yet to try any answer.will try it today

Comment: Hi Satendra ,Thanks for Help. Your answer is of great help.